# Updating MariaDB Connector/J - No Suitble Driver

Tags: java, android, mariadb, driver, remote-access

I have an existing Android app that works fine with an old version of the MariaDB connector:

```
implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:1.8.0'
```

If I update this Gradle reference to try and use the latest version:

```
implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client:3.3.0'
```

I get a "No suitable Driver Found" error. The MariaDB documentation indicates that existing code should work. The old code loads the driver:

```
Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver")
```

And then sets up the connection:

```
myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(myURL, info)
```

My Android app has the following parameters set:

```
    kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"}
```

and

```
sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

The connection string is valid (i.e., it hasn't changed):

```
"jdbc:mariadb://10.0.0.70:3306/weewx?user=xyz&password=myPass"
```

I am at a loss. I tried everything. Are there other parameters or dependencies required that I do not specify / understand? What things should I try, or look for?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your Java Language Level is set to 8, you can only use JDBC 4.2 compliant drivers, and can go up to 3.0, but NOT 3.3.

Please refer [Java Compatibility Page for MariaDB JDBC Drivers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#java-compatibility)

Comment: Confused, it should be compatible with my app. See:

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-j-releases/

Comment: Version 2.0.1 works, V3.0.3 did not. Tried V2.7.11, which resulted in a different error: "No Class Definition Found". Perhaps the same error to "no Suitable Driver Found"?  Is there a Gradle issue perhaps?

Comment: After more testing: V2.4.4 works, but V2.5.0 does not work. I cannot figure out what changed between these releases that causes the error: "No Class Definition Found". Perhaps the addition of JDBC 4.3 methods?